# how to send a notification to the customer after 30 minutes?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm  trying to send a notification after 30 minutes to the customer app after he clicks on confirm delivery . I created an event listener to send that notification but how can I make the listener listens to an event and send that notification after 30 muinutes ?

This is my confirm deliver function in APIController :

```
public function confirm_delivery(Request $request)
{
    $id = (int)$request->order_id;
    $order = Order::find($id);
    Order::where('user_id', $user->id)->find($id)->update(['stage' => 9]);
    $type = 'CUSTOMER_';
    $uuid = $user->uniqid;
    $order_id =$id;
    $order_no =$order->order_no;
    //Todo::Event to send notfifiction for user to rate place after 30 mins
    event(new CustomerRatePlaceEvent($type,$uuid,$order_id,$order_no));
    return ResponseHelper::customizedResponse(true, 1, 'Order delivered to customer.');
}
```

_Construct in the CustomerRatePlaceEvent :

```
public $type;
public $uuid;
public $order_id;
public $order_no;

public function __construct($type,$uuid,$order_id,$order_no)
{
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->uuid = $uuid;
    $this->order_id = $order_id;
    $this->order_no = $order_no;
}
```

EventServiceProvider:

```
 CustomerRatePlaceEvent::class => [
     CustomerRatePlaceListener::class,
 ],
```

CustomerRatePlaceListener:

```
public function handle($event)
{
    NotificationHelper::ٌratePlaceNotification($event->type,$event->uuid,$event->order_id,$event->order_no);
}
```

**(the notification code is inside a helper function and it works fine : NotificationHelper::ٌratePlaceNotification)**

Comment: You could use a queue. In queue, it lets you dispatch a job after a certain time.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues).

Comment: i would suggest cron job. it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue is enough for this task.

You should use delayed dispatching - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

When users use an api endpoint or create some entity you dispatch delaying 30 minutes.

Something like this:

```
SendNotification::dispatch($podcast)->delay(now()->addMinutes(30));
```

Comment: You will need to read the queue documentation for that and mould it according to your code.You can take help from this link if you want detailed explanation: 
https://blog.mailtrap.io/laravel-mail-queue/